# How to convert byte string to byte array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

View the file(downloaded by wget) in hex mode:

```
00000000: 4d86 1bcc d86e 1be2 bf73 42fb 8c22 b147  M....n...sB..".G
00000010: e175 50cd 096c 3ee5 6cfc 1ce7 3db8 867e  .uP..l>.l...=..~
00000020: 9d1d d198 87ab 85ef 73b1 4f7d 31ce d176  ........s.O}1..v
00000030: 2b58 318d 2d44 deba d054 1793 9d6d 2d35  +X1.-D...T...m-5
00000040: 0464 88d9 d29d fd81 a169 6589 617e 56ad  .d.......ie.a~V.
00000050: 72ea d50c 508a 2c34 89cd 8182 e488 0a69  r...P.,4.......i
00000060: 84bc 7e71 e2be 2551 dbf3 5d50 7be2 9eee  ..~q..%Q..]P{...
00000070: 0582 f014 a652 3943 40f5 28f8 3db8 5dfd  .....R9C@.(.=.].
00000080: b607 dbc8 f0f5 6eb4 7651 8363 5d23 edb8  ......n.vQ.c]#..
00000090: a4a0 8b14 503a 1e6e f7d8 5f54 d27f e8e4  ....P:.n.._T....
...
```

The file is encrypted, so no specific encoding.

```
const response = await axios.get(url);
const file = response.data;  // file.length is not expected
// "M���n�sB��"�G�uP�   l>�l��=��~�ј����s�O}1��v+X1�-D޺�T..."
Buffer.from(file);
// Uint8Array(805549) [77, 239, 191, ...]  // not expected
// and the length should be multiples of 16
```

What I want is: [77, 134, 27, ...]

Read the downloaded file by `fs` is alright

```
fs.readFile('xxx.bin', function(err, buffer){
  console.log(buffer);
  console.log(buffer.length % 16);  // 0
  console.log(new Uint8Array(buffer));
});
```

Comment: JavaScript is typeless....the closet thing you get when you use typeof keyword on a variable is "string", "number", "object" or "undefined".  You can create an array which will be typeof "object" then push content to it.

Comment: @SPlatten JavaScript **isn't** typeless. It's dynamically typed, but it has got types inside

Comment: @thinker3 what do you see if you evaluate `response.contructor.name`?

Comment: @CristianTraìna, ok, its not strick and once a variable has been assigned a value of a specific type nothing prevents a value of a different type from being assigned.

Comment: `new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(file))` should do it

Comment: @JonasWilms, if you do a typeof on any element of the array, what is the result?

Comment: I guess the encoding is the problem here. What's the encoding the server responds with?